# Hedge trimmer or pole trimmer for ivy overgrown in tree?

Tags: landscaping

What is the best to trim overgrowth of ivy out of a crepe myrtle tree, but just a few of the vines? I can use a ladder and get to trim the vine hanging in the area I want to trim out of the tree. What would be the best to use, a pole trimmer for trimming limbs or a hedge trimming to trim a bunch at one time?

Comment: pull it out in the winter after cutting it t the base.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to send pictures.  My vote would be pole pruners not hedge trimmers or anything powerful unless you are an expert with their use.  Crepe Myrtle is not a huge tree, pole pruners might be fine for higher up stuff but hand pruners might be best overall.